# Can characters stand in corner squares of a round room?

Tags: dnd-4e, battle-map

Can a character stand in any partial squares of a large round room, on the perimeter? And if so, do they have to squeeze for all of the squares that are not complete? Rules Compendium states that a creature takes up all of the space in its square, but maybe it’s disallowed altogether? Maybe only a squeeze into squares that have at least half surface area or more?

Answer (score 4):

Creatures occupy the squares appropriate to their size, which for Medium creatures is 1 square. In principle a Medium-sized character could squeeze into a partial square, but this is entirely at the DM's discretion and also a very bad idea for combat.

> When a Medium or smaller creature squeezes, the DM decides how narrow a space it can occupy. (Rules Compendium, page 250)